# Selectable TextView inside ScrollView with GestureDetector

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview, gesturedetector

I have TextView in my layout. If I set:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

users can select and copy text (part or all - it is ipmortant). But ScrolViews `GestureDetector` doesn't detect any gestures over TextView (for example onFling)

```
   GestureDetector gesturedetector = new GestureDetector(smsDetail.this,
            new OnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                        float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                    return false;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                       float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            , null);
    OnTouchListener gesturelistner = (v, event) -> gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    scrolloView.setOnTouchListener(gesturelistner);
```

if set

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

`GestureDetector` works fine.

How can I use `GestureDetector` and selectable `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

My soulution:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```